# Which SRAM derailleur is an upgrade to the X7?

Tags: derailleur, sram

The SRAM x7 is mated to a PG 1050.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need a GX 10 speed shifter to upgrade. The GX is roughly equal to the old X9 from the groupset family series X5,X7,X9.

You can still also get an X5 10 speed derailleur.

https://www.sram.com/en/sram/models/rd-gx-t21-a1

A quick search suggests they are commonly available and in production.

Comment: From 9 speed to 11 speed there was also an x.0, (the priciest) that had a titanium spring that was supposed to be better. Oddly, out of the many X.5, X.7 and X.9 I have on bikes, that X.0 was the only sram DR that ever failed on me. The spring broke during a commute home. (I was able to lock the DR in the middle of the cassette with zip ties and just use front DR to have a 3-speed...) This is all to say that an "upgrade" may not be an upgrade. We have 1000s of (road) miles on X.7s and X.9s, and I couldn't name a single thing that's better with the latter.